# Target Container Not a Dom element

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

I have been trying so long to hydrate but even the ReactDOM.render doesnt work .It says Target Container not a dom element.As of now I'm using only one page for SSR .[[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gX57D.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FzJzv.png) But as you can see there is  a div with id "con ".Because the other pages work fine (CSR) so only the about page doesnt work .And the hydration doest happen even though I have got the js files hhydrated and sent .Is there any way to help me

I have been expecting for the handlers to work well

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.